# What will happen if you beat Elena's high score?

Tags: uncharted-4

There's a scene in the chapter named "A normal life" in Uncharted 4 that you'll play Crash Bandicoot to beat Elena's highscore (which is a perfect run).

I know that you can't beat the highscore, except in the Epilogue, but what's the difference between this chapter's Crash Bandicoot version and the Epilogue's one, that makes it impossible to beat?

Answer (score 6):

You can't beat Elena's score as the epilogue gives you an extra life (and points). So playing the epilogue will give you an advantage over Elena's version.

Clearing it gives you an achievement.

IGN did a video on this [here](https://youtu.be/nyTWiQssE8M).

Comment: The video is likely showing the epilogue version. But if you can beat Elena's version then what happen next? Is there another cutscene apart from when you lose?

Comment: Apparently you can't beat the chapter 4's game as the epilogue gives you extra points.